# Converting string to date with as.Date in R

Tags: r, locale, as.date

I am trying to convert a character string to date in R.

string <- "August2018"

as.Date(x = string, format = "%B%Y")

The following code gives me only NA :(

From the documentation,
%B is the full month name in the current locale and
%Y is Year with century (4 digit year).

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html

I also tried to set my locale to "en_US.UTF-8" with the code:
Sys.getlocale (category = "LC_ALL"). This did not help either.

Can somebody please help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can paste a day and then use `as.Date(paste0(string, '01'), format = '%B%Y%d')#[1] "2018-08-01"` or with lubridate `myd(string, truncated = 1)#
[1] "2018-08-01"`

Comment: An alternative is to use the `zoo` package and zoo::as.yearmon(string).

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions and sorry for the late answer!